# Flutter - Ignore lint for tests breaks compiler and auto-import

Tags: flutter

Using an analysis option definition like below helps to disable lint warnings for tests files, but then i also don't get any compiler errors anymore nor the auto-import suggestions.

```
analyzer:
  exclude:
    - test/**
```

I tried also different variations but non of them worked. Any ideas how to solve this?

Android Studio Bumblebee | 2021.1.1 Patch 1
Flutter 2.10.1
flutter_lints: ^1.0.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding exclude rule, you can create another `analysis_options.yaml` file inside your test folder so that the analyzer would use the newly created file to analyze the test folder.

Comment: Hi, I tried this approach but once you run "flutter analyze" on your console or build server, you get all warnings again

Comment: after adding the new file you have to edit it and add the required lint rules you want the analyzer to ignore. these new rules will only be applied to the test folder.

Comment: Ok thanks, i just thought that its enough to overwrite the file with an empty set. I created now a file and disabled all checks i dont want to have. Nevertheless, it would be nicer if the exclusion of paths would work